# how to use setIcon function on android

Tags: android, menu, icons

Hello guys I m trying to set an Icon in a menuItem. I read the Android Developers Blog and it says:

```
public abstract MenuItem setIcon (int iconRes)
```

Change the icon associated with this item. This icon will not always be shown, so the title should be sufficient in describing this item. See Menu for the menu types that support icons.

This method will set the resource ID of the icon which will be used to lazily get the Drawable when this item is being shown.

Parameters :`iconRes` The new icon (as a resource ID) to be displayed.

Returns : This Item so additional setters can be called.

I should put as parameter an int. In particoulare the ID of my icon. But I can't figure out where I have to find this ID. I simply put the icon named "`badIcon.ico`" inside the drawable folder. Now should I proceed?
Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

this is so simple....
See this tutorial..[here](http://android-helper.blogspot.in/2011/04/android-simple-menu-example.html)

Create **menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item android:id="@+id/next"
              android:icon="@drawable/ic_next"
              android:title="@string/next" />
      <item android:id="@+id/previous"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_previous"
            android:title="@string/previous" />
      <item android:id="@+id/list"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_list"
            android:title="@string/list" /> 
</menu>
```

And now you will be able to set ICON on menu

Now in **CreateOptionMenu**

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
      inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
      return true;
    }
```

And to get that menu..

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case R.id.next:
            Toast.makeText(this, "You have chosen the " + getResources().getString(R.string.next) + " menu option",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
      …
      default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add icons to your menu item in static way you can write

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/yourId"
  android:icon="@drawable/badIcon"
  android:title="@string/yourTitle" /> 
</menu>
```

You can add icon programmatically like this

```
menu.add(0, MENU_TITLE, 0, "title").setIcon(R.drawable.badIcon);
```

Comment: Yes it was exaclty what I was searching for. This work perfectly. Just to be more precise.. in the example I ve seen online the sintax whas this:
menu.add(0, MENU_TITLE, 0, 243238).setIcon(98928299);

What that number mean and How can I set the icon using this kind of approach?

Comment: That number may be an Integer value of Auto generated class R. You can view those number by holding ctrl and clicking the R.drawable.badIcon. For example Click badIcon holding ctrl. you will see the Integer value at R class... And it is not useful because this number was The int value of their resources of their project..If you got what u were searching then Tick the correct button so that others will know u got your answer.. hope this will help..

Comment: I ve tried to hold ctrl and LeftClick on the icon (and it should works also for layout I guess) but nothing happens. Can you please explain me just how can I see these number in my case.. Thanks for the answer in any case :)

Comment: It is not used to navigate layout only. If you didn't get what those Integers are then Press Shift twice.. You will see a prompt **Search Everywhere** Then Press capital **R** you will see a class file something like 
'R(com.yourdomain.com)' . View code inside that class. you will understand What the numeric values were.. 
**Note : Never Edit those codes.**